# how change color of cite

Tags: citing

my code is \cite{chang2001}.

and

```
@article{chang2001,
  title={Training v-support vector classifiers: theory and algorithms},
  author={Chang, Chih-Chung and Lin, Chih-Jen},
  journal={Neural computation},
  volume={13},
  number={9},
  pages={2119--2147},
  year={2001},
  publisher={MIT Press}
}
```

and the result is color blue, i need color black

[image]

and configuration is

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliografía} % Bibliografía en español
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía} % Agrega la bibliografía al Índice.
    \bibliographystyle{apalike} % formato APA 

    \bibliography{perifericos/bibliografia}
```

Comment: Please show us the details of the `\usepackage[...]hyperref` instruction and of any and all `\hypersetup{...}` instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Package `hyperref` has an option `hidelinks` to hide the links from the user (no visual markup).
- The color of link categories can be changed with options `linkcolor`, `filecolor`, `urlcolor`, `citecolor`, ..., if option `colorlinks` is used. The color of rectangles around links are changed with `linkbordercolor`, `linkfilecolor`, ..., see the `hyperref` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=red,
    linktoc=all,
    citecolor=black
           }
```